# Samba share mounts as rw but non-root users can't write to it

Tags: linux, mount, network-shares, samba

On machine A with IP address 192.168.0.2, `/etc/samba/smb.conf` contains

```
[store]
path=/store
writeable=yes
valid_users=myusername
```

On machine B, when I I

```
mkdir /tmp/net/store
sudo mount -t cifs -o user=myusername //192.168.0.2/store /tmp/net/store
mount | grep store
```

I see

```
//192.168.0.2/store on /tmp/net/store type cifs (rw,relatime,vers=3.1.1,cache=strict,username=myusername,uid=0,noforceuid,gid=0,noforcegid,addr=192.168.0.2,file_mode=0755,dir_mode=0755,soft,nounix,serverino,mapposix,rsize=4194304,wsize=4194304,bsize=1048576,echo_interval=60,actimeo=1,user=myusername)
```

It is mounted `rw` and I can `ls /tmp/net/store` and read files within, but `touch /tmp/net/store/foo` fails for non-root users

```
% ls /tmp/net -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root      0 Aug 23 15:45 store

% sudo chmod +w /tmp/net/store

% ls /tmp/net -l
drwxr-xr-x 2 root   root      0 Aug 23 15:45 store
```

had no effect.

How do I make this samba share writeable on machine B for non-root users?

Comment: Could it have to do with `uid=0` ? ;)  If you are user ID 0 (aka ROOT), you can rw to hell and back on this mounted share.

Comment: remember that samba permissions stack atop file system permissions, so make sure the user in question can RW on the \store on the server.